# Binding loop detected on empty value

Tags: qt, qml

For some reason, when the TextField has empty value I get this error:

```
QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"
```

It only occurs when the value is empty, if I type something, the error disappears.

This field is used to capture an integer number, but since `TextField` does not manage integer inputs I have to convert it (from string to int) through a proxy property called `dp` :

```
    TextField {
        id: fld_decimal_places
    }
    Binding { target: aewm_obj.preferences; property: "dp_str"; value: fld_decimal_places.text }
    Binding { target: fld_decimal_places; property: "text"; value:  aewm_obj.preferences.dp_str }
```

The setter for property `dp_str` has this code:

```
Q_PROPERTY(int decimal_places READ get_decimal_places WRITE set_decimal_places NOTIFY decimal_places_changed)
Q_PROPERTY(QString dp_str READ get_dp_str WRITE set_dp_str NOTIFY dp_str_changed)
void Prefs::set_dp_str(QString p_dp_str) {
    int dp=0;
    if (p_dp_str.size()>0) {
        dp=p_dp_str.toInt();
    }
    qDebug() << "setting dp_str << " << p_dp_str << " to "<<dp << " integer value";
    if (this->decimal_places!=dp) {
        this->set_decimal_places(dp);
        qDebug() << "emitting dp_str_changed "  << p_dp_str;
        emit dp_str_changed(QString("%1").arg(dp));
    }
}
```

On the console I am seeing this when the TextField becomes empty:

```
setting dp_str <<  ""  to  0  integer value
set_decimal_places() to  0
emitting dp_str_changed  ""
get_dp_str() returning  "0"
qrc:/Preferences.qml:95:5: QML Binding: Binding loop detected for property "value"
```

Other methods are defined like this:

```
QString Prefs::get_dp_str() {
    qDebug() << "get_dp_str() returning " << QString("%1").arg(this->decimal_places);
    return QString("%1").arg(this->decimal_places);
}
void Prefs::set_decimal_places(int p_decimal_places) {
    if (this->decimal_places!=p_decimal_places) {
        this->decimal_places=p_decimal_places;
        this->settings->setValue("decimal_places",this->decimal_places);
        qDebug() << "set_decimal_places() to " << p_decimal_places;
        emit decimal_places_changed(this->decimal_places);        
    }
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I found out that if I comment the line that emits the signal `emit dp_str_changed(QString("%1").arg(dp)); ` I do not get this warning about loop anymore, but how should propagate the property change to other objects, if I remove `emit` statement?

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: The first binding is equivalent to: `aewm_obj.preferences.dp_str : fld_decimal_places.text` and the second binding: `fld_decimal_places.text : aewm_obj.preferences.dp_str` and obviously it is an infinite loop since if for example text changes it will also change dp_str using the first binding, but when modifying dp_str it activates the second binding modifying text and then it passes to the first binding, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc, if it would be pure QML then you would be right. But the other end is C++. If you were right, then why I don't get this error when the field is not empty? Why if I remove the `emit` statement this warning isn't showing? I have the same setup for another window and it shows no warnings. I think it is ok to have a C++ object bound to a QML engine property and viceversa without "bind loop" warnings.

Comment: what the magic of the binding on the C++ side is the signal, so when you do not emit the signal on the C++ side the problem is not generated.

Comment: In conclusion if C ++ does not notify the change the circle is not closed so the infinite loop is cut by eliminating the problem. About if you have another working code with the same idea only you know it, the community does not have those magic powers to know how you have implemented your other solution. so in my first comment I asked you for a [mcve]